# MediaPlayer error when trying to play from list

Tags: java, android, file, listview, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to build a recorder app, MainActivity records, other activity is for a listview that shows all the records and the media player, something went wrong with the media player, it worked fine before I built the second activity and then started some native error, so I thought I will build the second activity and will fix it... still get some native error. please help me to fix it!

I loged the filePath, seems fine.

Log.d(filePath, "The path exist");

08-08 12:05:49.298 2801-2801/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder D//storage/emulated/0/Recordings/07-08-2017 06:37:15 PM.mp4: The path exist

my code (Records Activity):

```
    public class RecordsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button play;
    static ListView recordList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
    String recordToPlay;
    MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_records);

        mp = new MediaPlayer();

        play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playbutton);
        recordList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

// Adapter with an ArrayList from the MainActivity that contains all the file names.

        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(RecordsActivity.this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, MainActivity.listRecord);
        recordList.setAdapter(listAdapter);


        recordList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //int chosenPosition = position;
                recordToPlay = listAdapter.getItem(position);

//made that toast to check if the name of the file set properly, it looks like it is.

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), recordToPlay+ " Chosen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Recordings/"+recordToPlay;


                    try {
                        mp.setDataSource(filePath);
                        mp.prepare();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                            //finalMp1.start();
                            mp.start();

                        }
                    });

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

logcat-

> 08-07 18:01:25.330 9157-9157/? I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
>   (already on) 08-07 18:01:25.445 9157-9157/? W/zygote: Unexpected CPU
>   variant for X86 using defaults: x86 08-07 18:01:25.822
>   9157-9157/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder I/InstantRun:
>   starting instant run server: is main process 08-07 18:01:26.392
>   9157-9206/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder D/OpenGLRenderer:
>   HWUI GL Pipeline
>
> > [ 08-07 18:01:26.423  9157: 9206 D/         ]
> >     HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa3d645c0, tid
> >     9206 08-07 18:01:26.655
> >     9157-9206/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder I/OpenGLRenderer:
> >     Initialized EGL, version 1.4 08-07 18:01:26.655
> >     9157-9206/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder D/OpenGLRenderer:
> >     Swap behavior 1 08-07 18:01:26.655
> >     9157-9206/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder W/OpenGLRenderer:
> >     Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying
> >     without... 08-07 18:01:26.655
> >     9157-9206/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder D/OpenGLRenderer:
> >     Swap behavior 0 08-07 18:01:26.657
> >     9157-9206/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder D/EGL_emulation:
> >     eglCreateContext: 0xa139c420: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2 08-07 18:01:26.658
> >     9157-9206/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder D/EGL_emulation:
> >     eglMakeCurrent: 0xa139c420: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa265dad0) 08-07
> >     18:01:26.664 9157-9206/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder
> >     W/android.hardware.graphics.mapper@2.0::Mapper: getService: found null
> >     hwbinder interface 08-07 18:01:26.667
> >     9157-9206/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder I/vndksupport: sphal
> >     namespace is not configured for this process. Loading
> >     /system/lib/hw/gralloc.ranchu.so from the current namespace instead.
> >     08-07 18:01:26.718 9157-9206/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder
> >     D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa139c420: ver 2 0 (tinfo
> >     0xa265dad0) 08-07 18:01:34.512
> >     9157-9206/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder D/EGL_emulation:
> >     eglMakeCurrent: 0xa139c420: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa265dad0) 08-07
> >     18:01:34.535 9157-9183/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder
> >     I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 4737(843KB)
> >     AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 64% free, 855KB/2MB, paused
> >     10.284ms total 110.547ms 08-07 18:01:34.558 9157-9168/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder I/zygote: Do partial
> >     code cache collection, code=13KB, data=21KB 08-07 18:01:34.558
> >     9157-9168/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder I/zygote: After code
> >     cache collection, code=13KB, data=21KB 08-07 18:01:34.558
> >     9157-9168/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder I/zygote: Increasing
> >     code cache capacity to 128KB 08-07 18:01:34.563
> >     9157-9206/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder D/EGL_emulation:
> >     eglMakeCurrent: 0xa139c420: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa265dad0) 08-07
> >     18:01:34.565 9157-9168/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder
> >     I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=13KB, data=38KB 08-07
> >     18:01:34.566 9157-9168/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder
> >     I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=13KB, data=38KB 08-07
> >     18:01:34.567 9157-9168/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder
> >     I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB 08-07 18:01:34.567
> >     9157-9168/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder I/zygote: JIT
> >     allocated 72KB for compiled code of void
> >     android.widget.TextView.(android.content.Context,
> >     android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) 08-07 18:01:34.589
> >     9157-9168/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder I/zygote: Compiler
> >     allocated 4MB to compile void
> >     android.widget.TextView.(android.content.Context,
> >     android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) 08-07 18:01:34.624
> >     9157-9206/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder D/EGL_emulation:
> >     eglMakeCurrent: 0xa139c420: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa265dad0) 08-07
> >     18:01:34.642 9157-9206/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder
> >     I/chatty: uid=10093(u0_a93) RenderThread identical 1 line 08-07
> >     18:01:34.692 9157-9206/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder
> >     D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa139c420: ver 2 0 (tinfo
> >     0xa265dad0) 08-07 18:01:34.698
> >     9157-9206/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder D/OpenGLRenderer:
> >     endAllActiveAnimators on 0x92173c00 (RippleDrawable) with handle
> >     0x921263f0 08-07 18:01:35.380
> >     9157-9206/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder D/EGL_emulation:
> >     eglMakeCurrent: 0xa139c420: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa265dad0) 08-07
> >     18:01:36.248 9157-9168/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder
> >     I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=125KB, data=69KB 08-07
> >     18:01:36.253 9157-9168/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder
> >     I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=123KB, data=54KB 08-07
> >     18:01:36.934 9157-9206/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder
> >     D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa139c420: ver 2 0 (tinfo
> >     0xa265dad0) 08-07 18:01:36.958
> >     9157-9206/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder
> >     D/RenderScript HIDL Adaptation: IRenderScriptDevice::getService()
> >     08-07 18:01:36.962 9157-9206/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder
> >     W/android.hardware.renderscript@1.0::Device: getService: found null
> >     hwbinder interface 08-07 18:01:36.963
> >     9157-9206/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder
> >     D/RenderScript HIDL Adaptation: IRenderScriptDevice::getService()
> >     returned 0x0 08-07 18:01:36.963
> >     9157-9206/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder
> >     D/RenderScript HIDL Adaptation: Using Fallback Path. 08-07
> >     18:01:36.975 9157-9206/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder
> >     D/RenderScript: Successfully queried cache dir:
> >     /data/user_de/0/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder/code_cache
> >     08-07 18:01:36.976 9157-9206/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder
> >     D/RenderScript: Setting cache dir:
> >     /data/user_de/0/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder/code_cache
> >     08-07 18:01:36.985 9157-9206/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder
> >     D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa139c420: ver 2 0 (tinfo
> >     0xa265dad0) 08-07 18:01:38.488
> >     9157-9168/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder I/zygote: Do partial
> >     code cache collection, code=124KB, data=67KB 08-07 18:01:38.488
> >     9157-9168/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder I/zygote: After code
> >     cache collection, code=124KB, data=67KB 08-07 18:01:38.488
> >     9157-9168/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder I/zygote: Increasing
> >     code cache capacity to 512KB
>
> 08-07 18:01:38.805 9157-9324/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder
>   E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)
>
> 08-07 18:01:38.809 9157-9157/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder
>   W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1 08-07
>   18:01:38.810 9157-9157/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder
>   W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer._prepare(Native Method)
>   08-07 18:01:38.810 9157-9157/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(MediaPlayer.java:1259) 08-07
>   18:01:38.810 9157-9157/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder.RecordsActivity$2.onClick(RecordsActivity.java:67)
>   08-07 18:01:38.810 9157-9157/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder
>   W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6219)
>   08-07 18:01:38.810 9157-9157/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24482) 08-07 18:01:38.810
>   9157-9157/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:769) 08-07 18:01:38.810
>   9157-9157/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 08-07 18:01:38.810
>   9157-9157/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 08-07 18:01:38.810
>   9157-9157/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540) 08-07
>   18:01:38.810 9157-9157/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder
>   W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   08-07 18:01:38.810 9157-9157/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>   08-07 18:01:38.810 9157-9157/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Comment: did so (I think) :)

Comment: Log `filePath` to see if the path exist

Comment: tried it on my phone now (Xperia z5 premium) this is new, just going into the RecordsActivity and this shows up on logcat-

08-07 18:42:11.827 17751-17751/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer could not be located....
08-07 18:42:11.827 17751-17751/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
08-07 18:42:11.827 17751-17751/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer could not be located....

Comment: 08-07 18:42:11.827 17751-17751/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0

Comment: I loged the filePath, seems fine.

 Log.d(filePath, "The path exist");

08-08 12:05:49.298 2801-2801/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder D//storage/emulated/0/Recordings/07-08-2017 06:37:15 PM.mp4: The path exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the reason were:
the file named with DateTime, when the format were like that:

```
String dateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy  hh:mm:ss aa", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
```

the MediaPlayer gets an error for some reason.

So I Changed it to:

```
String dateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy  hh-mm-ss aa", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
```

although I really prefer the hh:mm:ss

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to use `recordToPlay = MainActivity.listRecord.get(position);`

Comment: Same error 
08-07 18:37:50.333 27580-27593/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)